# PNG in Plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex, png

I have been presented with graphic files in the format .png.  I need to 
include them in a Plain TeX document.  How is that possible?  Is there a way
to convert them to .eps?

Comment: are you using classic dvi tex or pdftex?

Comment: Thanks for the 3 replies.  The day after I asked the question, I realized that my issue is not plain vs. LaTeX. but dvi vs. pdf[la]tex.  I have both .eps and .png figures, so I followed the advice of the 3rd respondent and used "convert" to get .eps files that work in dvips (which I'm used to).  A junior colleague got slightly better results with gimp instead of convert.  @lhf

Answer (score 5):

Use pdftex and the `graphicx` package from LaTeX with `eplain`

```
\input eplain
\beginpackages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\endpackages
```

Load your graphics with `\includegraphics{yourpng}`, and typeset your document with pdftex (not pdflatex).

If you find loading `eplain` too bloated, you may try `graphics.tex`, bundled in the [graphics-pln](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphics-pln) bundle.

```
\input graphicx
\includegraphics{yourpng}
```

Beware you may need to set the driver to match your engine. In the graphics.tex file change `\def\Gin@driver{dvips.def}` for `\def\Gin@driver{pdftex.def}`.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an image to eps, you can use `convert`, which you probably already have.

Just do `convert foo.png foo.eps`.